# MUI Icons used in shared React component library won't render: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, npm-workspaces

I've created a monorepo with a shared component library, but when I import components from that library that contain a MUI icon from @mui/icons-material I get the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

This is what I get when I console.log() an imported Icon

```
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
console.log(AddIcon)

{
  default: {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.memo),
    type: { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.forward_ref), render: [Function] },
    compare: null
  }
}
```

Everything else in the shared components is working fine, including the regular MUI components, and the icons work normally if I'm just adding them directly to my project so I can't figure out why they break in the shared components.

I have "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.1" in the peerDependencies of my shared library and "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.1" as a dependency in the project that I'm importing the shared components to.

Comment: It's an issue anytime there is an Icon is inside of the shared component I'm importing. If the Shared component were simply a button with an icon it would throw the same error I described: <Button><AddIcon /></Button> would not work but just <Button></Button> would

Comment: Having the exact same problem. I'm using Vite to test, tsc to build my packages. Seems somehow the default import gets messed up because the content of `default` in your `console.log(AddIcon)` is what should be the actual `AddIcon`...

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue using MUI with the turbo repo design starter (tsup). I don't like this hack, but it does appear to work.

```
import SaveBase from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import SvgIcon from '@mui/material/SvgIcon/SvgIcon';

const normalizeIcon = (Icon: typeof SvgIcon) => {
  return ((Icon as any).default ? (Icon as any).default : Icon) as typeof SvgIcon;
};

const SaveIcon = normalizeIcon(SaveBase);

<SaveIcon />
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing the import also works for me.

from

```
// import ([\w]+) from '@mui/icons-material/([\w]+)'
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
```

to

```
// import { $2 as $1 } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { Menu as MenuIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
```

Answer (score 0):

I built my packages with both *commonjs* and *es modules*. I have the *commonjs* in the root of the package and *es modules* in an **esm/** subdirectory. In my **esm/** subdirectory I have a **package.json** with just `{"type": "module"}`. I'm not using `exports` in the root **package.json**, but just `main` and `module` where `module` points to **./esm/index.js**. The output in **esm/** actually is the result of `tsc --target es6 --module esnext --outDir ./build/esm`.

With **package.json** in **esm/** subdirectory I get the exact error you pointed out and the icon import will be an object with `default` that points to the expected imported data. However, if I delete the **package.json** in **esm/** all is fine again. It also seems to greatly reduce startup time, so I'm guessing something is broken in my package setup.

I'm not sure if this also applies to you, but the symptons are definitely the same.